# Program works in debugging mode, but not when run via shortcut

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from one workbook to another. But when I run it via a macro shortcut, which is  Ctrl+Shift+O, it doesn't work.

But when I run my program in debugging mode, it is working as it should. I don't understand why.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit  

Sub CONSUMED()  
    Dim wp As Workbook, wc As Worksheet  
    Dim UVAL As Variant, erow As Integer, lastrow As Integer, E As Integer  

    UVAL = InputBox("Enter a code:") `user will enter the value, which user wants to shift.`
    Set wc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("consumption")
    erow = wc.Cells(wc.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row        
    Set wp = Workbooks.Open("F:\report\Book1.xlsm") ' where dtat will move'

    For E = erow To 7 Step -1
        If Cells(E, 11) = UVAL Then ' when uservalue(uval)  meets data from sheet'
            Application.CutCopyMode = True
            wc.Range(wc.Cells(E, 2), wc.Cells(E, 12)).Copy
            With wp.Sheets("Sheet1")
                lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 12)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                wc.Range(wc.Cells(E, 2), wc.Cells(E, "XFD")).Delete
            End With
            E = E - 1
        End If
    Next
    wp.Save
    wp.Close True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code.  Remove the tag and read [ask] and take the [tour] `doesnt run completely` is a horrible problem description.

Comment: When you open a workbook, the ActiveSheet changes. Your If statement at the top of your For/Next loop needs to be qualified to the appropriate worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Sub CONSUMED()
Dim wp As Workbook, wc As Worksheet
Dim UVAL As Variant, erow As Integer, lastrow As Integer, E As Integer

UVAL = InputBox("Enter a code:") 'user will enter the value, which user wants to shift.
Set wc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("consumption")
erow = wc.Cells(wc.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

 Set wp = Workbooks.Open("B:\Book1.xlsm") ' where dtat will move'
'Add this line make source workbook active
wc.Activate


For E = erow To 7 Step -1
'Convert Cell value to string InputBox returns string value
If CStr(Cells(E, 11).Value) = UVAL Then ' when uservalue(uval)  meets data from sheet'


Application.CutCopyMode = True

 wc.Range(wc.Cells(E, 2), wc.Cells(E, 12)).Copy

  With wp.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

 .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 12)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wc.Range(wc.Cells(E, 2), wc.Cells(E, "XFD")).Delete
   End With
 E = E - 1
End If
Next
wp.Save
wp.Close True
 Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: made necessary changes as per your suggestion. But it's not working. when i run program it just open another workbook and then stop working. @Wojciech Wojtulewski